# Is it possible to Import Namespace into SSRS Custom Code

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services

Is it possible to import the `System.Xml` Namespace into an SSRS report?

#### With Imports

When I use an imports statement in the report code properties like this:

```vb
Imports System.Xml

Public Function GetXMLInfo() As String
    Dim reader = new XmlReader()
    ' ....

End Function
```

I get the following error:

```
The definition of the report '/MyReport' is invalid.
There is an error in line 0 of custom code: 
[BC30465] 'Imports' statements must precede any declarations
```

#### Without Imports

However, when I remove the import statement in my code setting like this:

```vb
Public Function GetXMLInfo() As String
    Dim reader = new XmlReader()
    ' ....

End Function
```

I get this error instead:

```
The definition of the report '/MyReport' is invalid.
There is an error in line 2 of custom code: 
[BC30002] Name 'XmlReader' is not defined
```

**Question**: How can I import the [`XmlReader`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlreader) class into my SSRS Code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can refer to `XmlReader` by its fully qualified name (including namespace)

So use `System.Xml.XmlReader` instead of `XmlReader` like this:

```vb
Public Function GetXMLInfo() As String
    Dim reader = new System.Xml.XmlReader()
    ' ....

End Function
```